# How to close dialog box

Tags: jquery

I have very strange behavior, I am closing the dialog box in complete event of ajax call using this

```
     $.ajax({ 
        url: "",
        data     : { },
        type     : "POST",  
        dataType : "text",
        cache    : false,
        success: function(response) { // on success..
        },
        complete : function() {
             $("#dialogDiv").dialog("close");
             $("#dialogDiv").dialog("destroy");
             $("#dialogDiv").remove();
        },
        error : function(errMsg)
        {

            console.log("AJAX : submit : error");
            console.log(jsonToString(errMsg));
        }
    });
```

However my issue is it **sometimes close and sometimes not** in my local server, and many times it does not working on production sever, I am really not able to find out what is issue. Is there any way to forcefully close the window in complete event? Or anything other?

Comment: is there any error in the console?

Comment: Nope. There is no any error in console

Answer (score 1):

Check your source code, and make sure you aren't popping multiple dialogs.  Since you are using an `id` jQuery will only act upon the first DOM element with the matching `id` (since id's are supposed to be unique to the page).

If you want to close all the dialog's then I suggest moving your `$("#dialogDiv")` to a `class` and using the class selector `.` as such `$(".dialogDiv")`

Finally, you should cache your selectors, or even better leverage `chaining` [Quick Guide: Chaining in Jquery](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/).

Cache example:

```js
var $dialogDiv = $('#dialogDiv");  // use the $ in the var to say -- Hey this is a jQuery object
$dialogDiv.dialog("close");
$dialogDiv.dialog("destroy");
$dialogDiv.remove();
```

This is useful if you need to reuse the selector multiple times.  Otherwise you are forcing javascript to reparse the entire DOM structure for the same element.

Chaining Example:

```
$("#dialogDiv").dialog("close").dialog("destroy").remove();
```

This works because jQuery returns an object after performing the action.  You probably don't need `close` or `remove` in this case because `destroy` should take care of it for you, but I wouldn't have much of an example without them.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution, Very strange behavior but it is working, instead of closing popup in `complete` event i do close it in `done` event, and it is working

```
    $.ajax({ 
        url: "",
        data     : {},
        type     : "POST",  
        dataType : "text",
        cache    : false,
        success: function(response) { // on success..

        },
        complete : function() {

        },
        error : function(errMsg)
        {
            console.log("AJAX : submit : error");
            console.log(jsonToString(errMsg));
        }
    }).done(function() {
        $("#dialogDiv").dialog("close");
        $("#dialogDiv").dialog("destroy");
        $("#dialogDiv").remove();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening randomly then you can close dialog on success and error event separately as follow:

```
 $.ajax({ 
    url: "",
    data     : { },
    type     : "POST",  
    dataType : "text",
    cache    : false,
    success: function(response) { // on success..
         if(reponse == "correct"){
            $("#dialogDiv").dialog("close");
         }
    },        
    error : function(errMsg)
    {
        $("#dialogDiv").dialog("close");
        console.log("AJAX : submit : error");
        console.log(jsonToString(errMsg));
    }
});
```